# Route / to specific template

Tags: routing

I'm trying to route the homepage / to a specific template. In my routes.php file, i've tried these two without result:

```
return array(
    '/' => 'specific/_entry',
    '' => 'specific/_entry',
);
```

Answer (score 1):

A site's home page is routed via a special route `__home__`. I don't believe you can set that in `routes.php`, but it's worth a shot. Generally, you specify a Single as the homepage, and can set the template there. It defaults to `index`.

Comment: Your right, was not able to set it with that variable.

Comment: Did you try routing through a plugin's ```defineSiteRoutes()```? I've no idea if it makes a difference compared to ```routes.php```.

Comment: I don't think it would. I believe Craft does some scrubbing before it adds the `__home__` entry to the route. It's using Yii's router class and I don't believe `__home__` to be a proper route. Why not use a Single or include the other template in the `index.html` template?